# Disable unread count in the Skype dock icon

Tags: macos, skype, notifications, dock

Is there anyway to disable the unread count in the Skype dock icon? I don't want want to use the *Mark unread messages as read immediately* option, since I want to see what I missed when I switch back to Skype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is [to disable badge app icon in Notification Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58005/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-unread-count-badge-in-mountain-lions-mail-app)

Comment: There is no Skype in Mac OS Big Sur Notification settings.